# Import error when attempting to run python script from command line

Tags: python, ssl, command-line, importerror, schedule

I can run my python script within jupyter, but I want to be able to schedule it to run every morning by using windows task scheduler. In order to do this, I first need to make sure I can run it through the command line.
However, when I attempt to run the script I get an import error:

"ImportError: cannot import name 'ssl' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_' "

I do not understand why this happens and can I do to sort it out.

I have seen there similar questions where about running scripts from the command line but I do not see how can they answer this.

Comment: Show us the exact command to run the script within jupyter, and the exact command in the windows task scheduler.

Comment: @JohnGordon In jupyter I just press "Control+Enter" and that runs the code without errors. Within the command line, I move to the folder where python.exe and my script are saved and write the following: "python.exe MyScript.py"

Comment: Why are you using `python.exe` in the windows task scheduler?  Shouldn't it be `jupyter.exe` (or whatever the Jupyter command is)?

Comment: I am not. My ultimate purpose is to use windows task scheduler. But at the moment I just want to be able to run a python script (MyScript.py) within the command line of windows withouth import errors that do not show running within the anaconda prompt command line.

Comment: If the script works in Jupyter, but not in regular Python, then your Jupyter and Python environments must be different.  If your goal is to run the script from regular Python, then you must address the differences in environment, i.e. whatever versions of packages you have installed on Jupyter, you must also install for regular Python.

Comment: I see. When I click on "python.exe" a command line appears saying " Warning: This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environmnet has not been activated. Libraries may fail to load. To activate this environmnet please see http://conda.io.activation". Then by activating conda it should work, right? I type "conda activate" but this leads to a syntax error as well.

Comment: I don't know anything about conda or virtual environments.  Hopefully someone else can help.